# Get the parent array key of a multidimensional array key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have several array variables like this:

```
<?
$var_array["awal"]["kahiji"] = "Iyeu nu kahiji";
$var_array["awal"]["kadua"] = "Ayeuna kadua";
$var_array["akhir"]["sisanya"] = "Nu akhir pisan";
?>
```

I want to know the parent key of the key **"kadua"** which will produce **"awal"** in output, is it possible?, do I need to loop, or is there a simpler way to use functions from PHP ?, thanks in advance, your tricks or help will really help me.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to restructure your data.

You can't be sure that there won't be another parent for kadua that isn't awal so you will most likely have an array of keys unless you want to stop at the first or something like that.

I think this may be the sort of thing that object oriented programming could help you conceptualize.

Back to the question you actually asked, this is how I would try to solve it:

```
$first_keys = array();
foreach ($var_array as $key => $first_level){
    if (array_key_exists("kadua", $var_array[$key])){
        $first_keys[] = $key;
    }
}
//$first_keys has all first keys that had a second key of kadua
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that I have to restructure the array of data, but right now I just want to know if there is an easy way to solve the above problem, by the way thank you for your suggestions and tricks :)